# How to link a Vaadin Grid with the result of Spring Mono WebClient data

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin, spring-webclient, vaadin-flow

This seems to be a missing part in the documentation of Vaadin...

I call an API to get data in my UI like this:

```
@Override
public URI getUri(String url, PageRequest page) {
    return UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(url)
            .queryParam("page", page.getPageNumber())
            .queryParam("size", page.getPageSize())
            .queryParam("sort", (page.getSort().isSorted() ? page.getSort() : ""))
            .build()
            .toUri();
}

@Override
public Mono<Page<SomeDto>> getDataByPage(PageRequest pageRequest) {
    return webClient.get()
            .uri(getUri(URL_API + "/page", pageRequest))
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {
            });
}
```

In the Vaadin documentation (https://vaadin.com/docs/v10/flow/binding-data/tutorial-flow-data-provider), I found an example with `DataProvider.fromCallbacks` but this expects streams and that doesn't feel like the correct approach as I need to block on the requests to get the streams...

```
DataProvider<SomeDto, Void> lazyProvider = DataProvider.fromCallbacks(
     q -> service.getData(PageRequest.of(q.getOffset(), q.getLimit())).block().stream(),
     q -> service.getDataCount().block().intValue()
);
```

When trying this implementation, I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.core.codec.CodecException: Type definition error: [simple type, class org.springframework.data.domain.Page]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `org.springframework.data.domain.Page` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
 at [Source: (io.netty.buffer.ByteBufInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
grid.setItems(lazyProvider);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have experience with vaadin, so i'll talk about the deserialization problem.

Jackson needs a `Creator` when deserializing. That's either:

1. the default no-arg constructor
2. another constructor annotated with `@JsonCreator`
3. static factory method annotated with `@JsonCreator`

If we take a look at spring's implementations of `Page` - `PageImpl` and `GeoPage`, they have neither of those. So you have two options:

1. Write your custom deserializer and register it with the `ObjectMapper` instance

The deserializer:

```
public class PageDeserializer<T> extends StdDeserializer<Page<T>> {

    public PageDeserializer() {
        super(Page.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Page<T> deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JacksonException {
        //TODO implement for your case
        return null;
    }
}
```

And registration:

```
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addDeserializer(Page.class, new PageDeserializer<>());
objectMapper.registerModule(module);
```

2. Make your own classes extending `PageImpl`, `PageRequest`, etc. and annotate their constructors with `@JsonCreator` and arguments with `@JsonProperty`.

Your page:

```
public class MyPage<T> extends PageImpl<T> {

    @JsonCreator
    public MyPage(@JsonProperty("content_prop_from_json") List<T> content, @JsonProperty("pageable_obj_from_json") MyPageable pageable, @JsonProperty("total_from_json") long total) {
        super(content, pageable, total);
    }
}
```

Your pageable:

```
public class MyPageable extends PageRequest {

    @JsonCreator
    public MyPageable(@JsonProperty("page_from_json") int page, @JsonProperty("size_from_json") int size, @JsonProperty("sort_object_from_json") Sort sort) {
        super(page, size, sort);
    }
}
```

Depending on your needs for `Sort` object, you might need to create `MySort` as well, or you can remove it from constructor and supply unsorted sort, for example, to the super constructor. If you are deserializing from input manually you need to provide type parameters like this:

```
JavaType javaType = TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructParametricType(MyPage.class, MyModel.class);
Page<MyModel> deserialized = objectMapper.readValue(pageString, javaType);
```

If the input is from request body, for example, just declaring the generic type in the variable is enough for object mapper to pick it up.

```
@PostMapping("/deserialize")
public ResponseEntity<String> deserialize(@RequestBody MyPage<MyModel> page) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok("OK");
}
```

Personally i would go for the second option, even though you have to create more classes, it spares the tediousness of extracting properties and creating instances manually when writing deserializers.

Comment: thanks for your very detailed answer!!

Answer (score 2):

There are two parts to this question.

The first one is about asynchronously loading data for a `DataProvider` in Vaadin. This isn't supported since Vaadin has prioritized the typical case with fetching data straight through JDBC. This means that you end up blocking a thread while the data is loading. Vaadin 23 [will add support](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/pull/12378) for doing that blocking on a separate thread instead of keeping the UI thread blocked, but it will still be blocking.

The other half of your problem doesn't seem to be directly related to Vaadin. The exception message says that the Jackson instance used by the REST client isn't configured to support creating instances of `org.springframework.data.domain.Page`. I don't have direct experience with this part of the problem, so I cannot give any advice on exactly how to fix it.

Comment: Thanks Leif, support for webclient/mono/... would be a great addition in Vaadin. Is this scheduled or already in the backlog? You are right about the second part of the question, not related to Vaadin, my fault, the answer of Chaosfire is correct in this case.

Comment: OK Leif, if I accept @chaosfire as the correct answer here? He has put a lot of work, detail and love in it...

Comment: Yep. The other answer solves the main problem. I'm just giving context to the part that isn't a direct problem. Non-blocking data provider isn't on the backlog. I agree that it would be a great addition but at the same time we have so many other great addition that we also want to prioritize.