# How to add No Argument Constructor to Java class from another package?

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to read a json file and convert to Object and this works fine for other classes but in this case my model has `GeoJsonMultiPolygon` which is from `package org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.geo;` and **does not contain a constructor with no arguments**

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.geo.GeoJsonMultiPolygon` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)


at [Source: (BufferedInputStream); line: 12, column: 5] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->data.countryboundaries.CountryBoundaries["geometry"])
```

Model:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString()
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Document(collection = "country-boundaries")
public class CountryBoundaries {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private String type;
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private CountryBoundariesProperties properties;
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private GeoJsonMultiPolygon geometry;
}
```

Code:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        InputStream is = Country.class.getResourceAsStream("/country-boundaries.json");
        List<CountryBoundaries> countryBoundaries = mapper.readValue(is,  new TypeReference<>(){});
        countryBoundariesRepository.saveAll(countryBoundaries);
```

How can I bypass this error since I'm not able to modify code from a library and fill the geometry object using the ObjectMapper?

Comment: Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71022383/how-to-link-a-vaadin-grid-with-the-result-of-spring-mono-webclient-data/71033265#71033265). It deals with the exact same problem - deserialization of classes without default constructor. It's about `Page`, but the same principle is applicable to your case.

Comment: @Chaosfire thanks but this is way too much stuff for a simple issue. Any simplers solution?

Comment: This method is tested and it works(with pages, i have not had dealings with geojson). Check my answer for simpler, but untested, solution. I have not used this module before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check static methods of [GeoJsonModule](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/geo/GeoJsonModule.html). It contains modules containing serializers and deserializers for geo json classes.

Register with your instance of `ObjectMapper`.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(GeoJsonModule.geoJsonModule());
```

`geoJsonModule()` contains both serializers and deserializers, if you need only deserializers use `deserializers()`.

Comment: perfect. thanks!!